# What are the pros and cons of using selenium and TTCN 3 for automation? Which one of the two is better in which scenario?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

What are the pros and cons of using selenium and TTCN 3 for automation? Which one of the two is better and in which scenario?

Comment: Priya, your question is a little vague and would require much more than a brief answer. You might limit your question by defining your project and the scenario's you intend to automate. Then do the leg work to list pro's and con's of each framework and then ask others for their experiences.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pros and cons of Selenium as:

Pros:

- It is an Open Source
- It supports all browsers like IE, Firefox, Mozilla, Safari
- It also supports all Operating Systems.

Cons:

- Selenium IDE does not supports loop and data driven testing
- It has no option to verify the images.

Comment: you could very any binary sequence (image, pdf, ...) by downloading it and compare the binary sequence with the expected one.